# ng-hide & ng-show in leaflet legend

Tags: arrays, angularjs, leaflet, ng-hide

I tried to create a leaflet legend using the 'ng-show' and 'ng-hide' attributes.
Unfortunately, the legend is not created on site load but on map load.
The attributes don't seem to work if they are added with javascript directly.

This code:

```
  onAdd: function() {
    var controlDiv = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'air-quality-legend');
    controlDiv.setAttribute('ng-hide', 'true');
    controlDiv.className = "airQualityIndex";
    L.DomEvent
      .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
      .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault);
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('table');
    var td = document.createElement('table');
    td.innerHTML = "test";
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    controlDiv.appendChild(table);
    return controlDiv;
  }
```

[Produces that output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu5Tj.png)
As described there is a table when there should not.
Is there any way to add 'ng-hide' or 'ng-show' via javascript on runtime?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to compile the DOM of your custom control. To do that, you'll need to inject `$compile` into your controller, then after having added the control to your map use the `getContainer` method on your control instance and run `$compile` on it and attach it to the scope:

Control:

```
L.Control.Custom = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: function () {
        var container =  L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-custom')
            header = L.DomUtil.create('h1', 'leaflet-control-custom-header', container);

        header.textContent = 'NG-Hide test';
        header.setAttribute('ng-hide', 'hide');

        return container;
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller', [
             '$scope', 'leaflet', '$compile',
    function ($scope,   leaflet,   $compile) {
        $scope.hide = false;
        leaflet.map.then(function (map) {
            var control = new L.Control.Custom().addTo(map);
            $compile(control.getContainer())($scope);
        });
    }
]);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xzRwTp9OZ8Zp8v7ktt2c?p=preview